# How to account for clustering when calculate Spearman coefficient in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, correlation

I have a group of people who had their drug concentrations measured by using blood and hair over time (i.e., everyone had three values measured by blood samples and another three values measured by hair samples). I wanted to calculate the Spearman coefficient between the two measurements, but I don't know how to account for the repeated measures within individuals.  Is there a way to do that in R?

```
id<-rep(c(1:100),times=3) ##id variable
df1<-data.frame(id)
df1$var1 <- sample(500:1000, length(df1$id))  ##measurement1
df1$var2 <- sample(500:1000, length(df1$id))  ##measurement2
cor.test(x=df1$var1, y=df1$var2, method = 'spearman') ## this doesn't account for clustering within individuals
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the R-package 'rmcorr' provides the functionality you are looking for. The package helps to compute repeated measures correlation:

```
install.packages("rmcorr")

rmcorr::rmcorr(participant = id, measure1 = var1, measure2 = var2, dataset = df1)
```